# How to smoothly do CSS animation without break at the end

Tags: html, css, css-animations

With this below code running, you can see after the end of a few seconds its break the animation, not running smoothly. I want to run it continuously smoothly in the same width I have defined. Please help , here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rq0dweyn/1) also

```css
.tech-slideshow {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.tech-slideshow > div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 126px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcC0b.png) repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-1 {
  animation: moveSlideshow 8s linear infinite;
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  background-position: 0 -200px;
  animation: moveSlideshow 15s linear infinite;
}
.tech-slideshow:hover .mover-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  100% { 
    transform: translateX(-66.6666%);  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tech-slideshow">
  <div class="mover-1"></div>
  <div class="mover-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why -ve vote please response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can animate the position of the background, for example, move it to the left by the width of the image, so when the animation ends and starts again, you won’t actually see the difference. In this case, the width of your background image is **26px**, therefore, you need to swipe the background to the left to the width of this background. In general, there are a lot of options, it all depends on what task you need to solve.

```
@keyframes moveSlideshow {
   100% {
     background-position-x: -26px;
   }
}
```

Also put the desired animation speed.